# Adding geom_text to a circular barplot

Tags: r

I want to create a circular barplot that shows how the production of films has increased over time. I can create the graph itself but when trying to add labels to the bars it goes completely wrong. Any insight - and why the graph gets so radically changed - would be much appreciated. TIA.

I think it's to do with the ylim value but I'm not sure.

```
ratings <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-01-08/IMDb_Economist_tv_ratings.csv")
ratings$year_rel <-year(ratings$date)


#data 
ratings_bar <- ratings %>%
  select(titleId, year_rel) %>%
  add_count(titleId) %>%
  group_by(year_rel) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(n)) %>%
  filter(year_rel >= 2000) %>%
  mutate(id = seq(1,19))

#Make labels
label_data <- ratings_bar
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <-  90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar 
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)

label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

#make graph
ratings_bar %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year_rel, y = total)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "darkblue", fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.7) +
  ylim(-100,1200) + #i think this is where the error arrives
  theme_minimal() +
  theme( axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm")) +
  coord_polar(start = 0) +# Up to here the code plots a circular barplot correctly
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=year_rel+10, label=total, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE )
```

Until the penultimate line it creates a label-less barplot, however after that it creates a blue looking mark...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new data set within `geom_text` seems to be the problem. The coordinate systems does not seem to fit, which makes sense, since you y-variable in `ratings_bar` runs from `211` to `784` while your y-variable in `label_data` runs from `2000` to `2018`. To avoid this I (1) do not introduce a second data set in the data argument of `geom_text`, (2) only add `labels` in the aes-argument, and (3) switch the order of the ggplot-statements by first adding `geom_text` and then adding the `coord_polar` statement.

Is there any particular reason that you add `10` to `y = year_rel` in the `geom_text` argument?

```
    ratings_bar %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = year_rel, y = total)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "darkblue", fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.7) +
        ylim(-100,1200)  + 
        theme_minimal() +
        geom_text(aes(label=total),
                  hjust = label_data$hjust,
                  color = "black",
                  fontface = "bold",
                  alpha = 0.6,
                  size = 2.5,
                  angle = label_data$angle) +
                  coord_polar(start = 0) + 
        theme( axis.text = element_blank(),
               axis.title = element_blank(),
               panel.grid = element_blank(),
               plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm"))
```